# Convert PDF to JPG / Images without using a specific C# Library

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, ghostscript.net

is there a free **C# library** (**.dll**) to convert **PDF** to **images** ?

I tried this one :

> https://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/

But it doesn't work, I got this error :

```
  Could not load file or assembly 'libpdf.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified    module could not be found.
```

iTextSharp doesn't implement a function like that either..

EDIT:

I didn't use ghost scrpit because you had to install it before on the computer

But now I found a solution : if you load manualy the dll it works

> http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/465418

```
    public void PDFToImage(string file, string outputPath, int dpi)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

        Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer rasterizer = null;
        Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo vesion = new Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), path + @"\gsdll32.dll", string.Empty, Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL);

        using (rasterizer = new Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer())
        {
            rasterizer.Open(file, vesion, false);

            for (int i = 1; i <= rasterizer.PageCount; i++)
            {
                string pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + "-p" + i.ToString() + ".jpg");

                Image img = rasterizer.GetPage(dpi, dpi, i);
                img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }

           rasterizer.Close();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Given the 1.8 million google hits that your question title generates, the answer is a resounding Yes.

Comment: Yes, I know, but tried five different lib, none is working.
I changed my question.

Comment: @baaron What do you mean by doesn't work? No output? , or an error message?, or the file corrupt? Please clarify the word "doesn't work"

Comment: http://www.yiigo.com/guides/csharp/how-to-pdf-convert-jpeg.shtml this should work

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years I have this error : https://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/issues/detail?id=3

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years thank you. I found a better solution.

Comment: Congratulations! Way to go

Comment: @baaron, what is the better solution?

Comment: @baaron- Can't be more thankful to you for the ghostscript solution. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski the solution is in the "EDIT" part

Comment: there is now nuget  ghostscript.net