# How to Print all pdf file, Images and docs file from folder in .net C# with print preview?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, doc

so basically what my task is like below.

My application is able to print multiple files with a different format in single preview and print button, files can be an image, pdf or doc.

so for that, I put below logic for printing and showing print preview option.

```
    List<string> elements = new List<string>();
    private int ElementCounter;
    private int page;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           try
        {
            var Files = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\Desktop\").GetFilesByExtensions(".png", ".pdf",".doc",".docx");

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {

                elements.Add(file.FullName);
                ElementCounter++;

            }

            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(elements[page]),e.MarginBounds);
            page++;
            e.HasMorePages = page < elements.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        page = 0;
    }
```

but above code is working fine only for images I am not able to show a preview of pdf and doc files. so my question is how can I show a preview of all pdf files and doc files

Any help I will highly appreciate

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c-sharp) try to use code from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the interest but I am looking for print preview before printing.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply convert the Docs and PDFs to images, such that you can display all the formats in the same way using the working code you have now. Here is a SO post for [PDF->PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905169/how-to-convert-pdf-files-to-image) and one for [DOC->PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217591/convert-doc-docx-to-png).